# GoのWAF、MartiniでJsonをストリーミングしたい

Tags: go, streaming

GoのアプリケーションにMartiniというフレームワークを使っています。
そこで質問です。
MartiniでJsonをストリーミングするにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
私は2通りの方法でやってみましたがどちらも1つのレスポンスになってしまいます。

**方法1**

MartiniのJsonレンダリングのためのミドルウェアRender(https://github.com/martini-contrib/render) を使った方法

```
func Handler(r render.Render){  

    /*抜粋*/
    for _,v := range data{
        r.JSON(200, v)  
        time.Sleep(2*time.Second)  
    }
}
```

**方法2**
ResponseWriterを使った方法

```
func Handler(res http.ResponseWriter){

    /*抜粋*/
    for _, v := range data{
        d, _ := json.Marshal(v)
        res.Write(d)
        res.(http.Flusher).Flush()
        time.Sleep(2*time.Second)
    }
}
```

どのようにすればストリーミングを実現できるのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.Hijacker`を使ってTCPソケットに直接書き込めばストリーミングできると思います。

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
)

func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()
    m.Get("/", Handler)
    m.Run()
}

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    hj, _ := w.(http.Hijacker)
    conn, bufrw, _ := hj.Hijack()
    defer conn.Close()

    bufrw.WriteString("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")
    bufrw.WriteString("Content-Type: application/json\r\n")
    bufrw.WriteString("Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n")
    bufrw.WriteString("\r\n")
    bufrw.Flush()

    enc := json.NewEncoder(bufrw)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        data := map[string]interface{}{"message": "hi!", "id": i}
        enc.Encode(data)
        bufrw.Flush()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとう御座います。できました!